# delete and find record mysql table by mtaching witha nother table

Tags: mysql

I can easily search icecat_cache for a single  value from product table using

```
SELECT * FROM `icecat_cache` WHERE `ident` LIKE '%FAN8X25TX3L%'
```

and then delete it

But i cant figure out how to  find values that dont exist in product table and delete them from icecat_cache.

icecat_cache table looks like this

```
     ident                          |  status
    ----------------------------------------------
        StarTech.com_FAN8X25TX3L    |    1
--------------------------------------------------
        hp_Fr4567                   |    1
-------------------------------------------------
        samsung_d345674             |    1
-------------------------------------------------
        hp_ser345                   |    1
------------------------------------------------
        toshiba_dff345              |    1
------------------------------------------------
        hp_se3453                   |    1
------------------------------------------------
```

Product table loooks like

```
id | model       |stock
-----------------------
1  | Fr4567      |Y
-----------------------
2  | se3453      |Y
 --------------------
3  |FAN8X25TX3L  |Y
```

As you see from the above example d345674 ,dff345  and ser345   dont exit in the product table. At the moment icecat_cache has over 500k items while products table only has 180k.

whats is the best way to delete them

Answer (score 0):

- Do a `Left Join` between the two tables. Consider `icecat_cache` as your left-most table, as you want to consider all the row from it.
- In join condition, you can specify the `LIKE %..%` rule.
- Now, consider only those rows where there is no matching entry in the `Product` table, using `Where Product.model IS NULL`
- You can Delete **only** from the `icecat_cache` table, by specifying only its name/aliase in the `Delete` clause.

Try the following query:

```
DELETE 
  ic
FROM icecat_cache AS ic 
LEFT JOIN Product AS p ON ic.ident LIKE CONCAT('%',p.model,'%')
WHERE p.model IS NULL
```

Comment: the above query did not work.i left it to run for good one hour and not a single  record was deleted.

Comment: @naf It will be inefficient because you are using `Like %..%`, which is basically  a full table scan. How many rows do you have in both the tables ?

Comment: thanks for replying  .200k in products and 500k  in icecat_cache

Comment: @naf Is it 100% that values in the product table will always be **suffixes** in the icecat_cache table ?

Comment: yes . it will always be suffixed. it will only be in the front. like StarTech.com_FAN8X25TX3L  not like  FAN8X25TX3L_StarTech.com . so i am note sure if i need  %model % . wont %model be enough

Comment: @naf yes precisely. Try this instead: `DELETE 
  ic
FROM icecat_cache AS ic 
LEFT JOIN Product AS p ON ic.ident LIKE CONCAT('%',p.model)
WHERE p.model IS NULL`

Comment: @naf If it still takes a lot of time, we first need to check, how much time does it take to select alone first. In that case, try: `Select * from icecat_cache as ic left join Product as p on ic.ident like Concat('%', p.model)`